# How to set dynamic content to a tooltip?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I need to make a call to an api to return the tooltip content. Does anyone know,  when setting a tooltip, how to acess the arguments in the dataItem, pass them to a function which returns the tooltip content?

I've seen [this](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/TooltipTemplatePoint/) and this [example](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/chart/tooltips/#series-tooltip) but I'cant understand how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chart provides tooltip templates, as shown in the [chart tooltip online demos](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/chart/elements/tooltips/). These allow custom tooltips to be created:

```
<kendo-chart-tooltip>
  <template kendoSeriesTooltipTemplate let-value="value">
      Default Content {{ value }}
  </template>
</kendo-chart-tooltip>
```

You can use pipes on the `value` to process it, or render a custom component. Each series can have its custom tooltips, if needed:

```
<kendo-chart-series-item>
  <kendo-chart-series-item-tooltip>
    <template let-value="value">
       Series 1 value: {{ value }}
    </template>
  </kendo-chart-series-item-tooltip>
</kendo-chart-series-item>
```

To make an API call, create a component that makes the request (and probably caches it) and use it in the tooltip template:

```
<kendo-chart-tooltip>
  <template kendoSeriesTooltipTemplate let-value="value">
     <my-series-details-tooltip [value]="value"></my-series-details-tooltip>
  </template>
</kendo-chart-tooltip>
```

Here is a [plunker demo that shows this](http://plnkr.co/edit/MhtSWusgpisfolwjjgaI?p=preview).

Comment: Perfect! It was so simple! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just letting you know link is now broken.

Comment: Here's the link: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/SeriesTooltipTemplateDirective/. It would be helpful to link to this on the TooltipComponent help page. I take it we can't access dataItem?